# Delete ball element from ObservableList upon collision with rectangle

Tags: java, animation, javafx

So, I'm trying to create an animation with bouncing balls. Everything is working good except that I got stuck with a simple thing.

I wanted to code such a feature that whenever any ball touches rectangle the ball will disappear.

I store balls in:

```
private ObservableList<Ball> balls = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Rectangle is stuck in a single point and it shouldn't move:

```
rectangle.relocate(675, 50);
```

I thought it will be simply enough to do:

```
if (rectangle.intersects(b2.getCenterX(), b2.getCenterY(), b2.getRadius()/2, b2.getRadius()/2))
```

And it catches the moment of the collision between ball and rectangle, but then I have no idea how to make this ball disappear. I thought it will be simply enough to:

```
balls.remove(b2);
```

But even for me it doesn't really makes sense. I'm sitting with this simple problem for the couple of hours and I got stuck, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `Ball`? How are you making it appear in the first place?

Comment: Honestly, I did find this: https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842 and then I just made some bigger or smaller changes, but the idea stands the same, so creating balls is pretty much the same.

Comment: Well, if you have the listener on the list, it should work. It's going to be pretty much impossible for anyone to help unless you create a [MCVE] (which would need to be much simpler than that example).